# Trailing '\x00' characters in Tensor when numpy string array is returned from tf.py_func

Tags: python, tensorflow

When a numpy string array returned from a function invoked by `tf.py_func` would have fixed string length with trailing '\x00' characters instead of "natural" variable string length without padding.

Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def main():
    def foo(x):
        a = np.asarray(['abc', 'd'], dtype=np.string_)
        return a

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        f = tf.py_func(foo, [tf.constant(1)], (tf.string))
        f = tf.Print(f, [f, tf.shape(f)])

        actual = sess.run(f)
        print actual
```

Prints out:

```
[abc d\000\000][2]
```

A small workaround I am using is:

```
f = tf.string_split(f, delimiter='\x00', skip_empty=True).values
```

Is this a TF issue or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Returning a list instead of a ndarray seems to work:

```
def foo(x): 
  a = [['abc', 'd']]
  return a
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
a = np.asarray(['abc', 'd'], dtype=np.string_)
```

to

```
a = np.asarray(['abc', 'd'], dtype=object)
```